# How to compare two lists in Python efficiently?

Tags: python, list

I have recently started working with Python. I know it might be a silly question as it sounds very basic question to me.

I need to compare `first list` with `second list` and if `first list` values are there in the `second list`, then I want to return true.

```
children1 = ['test1']
children2 = ['test2', 'test5', 'test1']

if check_list(children1):
    print "hello world"


def check_list(children):
    # some code here and return true if it gets matched.
    # compare children here with children2, if children value is there in children2
    # then return true otherwise false
```

In my above example, I want to see if `children1` list value is there in `children2` list, then return true.

Comment: You can just use the normal equals comparison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `all`

```
def check_list(child1, child2):
    child2 = set(child2)
    return all(child in child2 for child in child1)

children1 = ['test1']
children2 = ['test2', 'test5', 'test1']
print check_list(children1, children2)
```

Returns

```
True
```

Comment: If `child2` is large it is much more efficient to convert it to a `set`.

Comment: @Tim Thanks Tim :) Included that in the answer :)

Answer (score 4):

`set`s have an [`issubset`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set.issubset) method, which is conveniently overloaded to `<=`:

```
def check_list(A, B):
    return set(A) <= set(B)

check_list(children1, children2) # True
check_list([1,4], [1,2,3]) # False
```